# Why are $(q,p)$ in cotangent bundle instead of tangent bundle?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, classical-mechanics, tangent-bundle, co-tangent-space

In the book of Frankel, *The geometry of Physics*, at page 55, he states that

> [...] Thus,
>
> $$p_i^{U} = \sum_j p_j^V (\frac{ \partial q_i^{U}}{\partial q_i^{V} }
>  ),$$
>
> and so the $p’s$ represent then not the components of a vector on the
>   configuration space $M^n$ but rather a covector. The $q’s$ and $p’s$
>   then are to be thought of not as local coordinates in the tangent
>   bundle but as coordinates for the cotangent bundle.

However, I cannot understand why $p's$ represent a covector. I mean, I don't see any connection between the result about how does p's transform for a given coordinate patch to another, with why p's are convectors.

**Edit:**

In [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16460/how-to-see-the-phase-space-of-a-physical-system-as-the-cotangent-bundle?rq=1#comment30543_16462) question/comment, a similar thing is asked/answered, but none of the answers gives a clear & complete answer. For example, I don't understand why $p$ is a covector ?

Comment: What is unclear or incomplete about the linked question & answer?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz see my last edit please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to understand the situation clearly, let us analyse it in more neutral environment, where the terminology and the physical properties of the variables does not block our view.

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, and $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ be smooth map. Later, $M$ be our tangent bundle in question, and $f$ be a Lagrangian. Let $y \in M$ be any point, and $\phi: y\in U\subseteq M \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be local chart around $y$ s.t $\phi(y) = (x_1(y), ..., x_n(y)) = (0,...,0)$.

Let use define

$$g_i (y) = \frac{\partial (f)}{ \partial x_i}|_\vec 0 := \frac{d }{dt }((f \circ x_i^{-1})(t))|_{t=0},  $$
where $x_i^{-1}: J \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to U$ s.t $\phi \circ x_i^{-1} = id_J$.

($g_i$ later be the momenta $p_i$)

However, since $\mathbb{R}$ is itself a smooth manifold,

$$=df(p, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i } ),$$

Thus, $g_i (\_) = df(\_, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i } ) : M \to \mathbb{R}$.

Now, the above analysis hold for any smooth manifold $M$. In particular, for any smooth manifold $N$, let $M:= TN$, and $f: = L$, $g_i:= p_i$. Hence,

$$p_i: TN \to \mathbb{R},$$
thus, $p_i \in T^* N.$

Comment: Thanks for the down vote!

Comment: What exactly do you want to say? That in $\dot p=-\partial_xH$ the components $\dfrac{\partial H}{\partial x^i}$ are the coordinates of a covector? Why do you relabel your variables? Use the final name from the start, $q$ for the point and $p$ for the impulse.

Comment: @LutzL Please reread the first paragraph of the answer.

Comment: I read it. It still makes no sense for such a short article format. While relatively often $p$ is used for "point", more often it is just simply $x$, and in symplectic geometry $q$.

Comment: @LutzL Well, it makes a lot of sense to me because the notation I use shaped the way how I think, so that "neutral" labels help me a lot.